# Convert int[][] to String

Tags: java

I have a 2d array and i want to convert it to String example

I want to convert `int[][] p` to `String` and I use `toString` but it fail.

```
int [][] p = new int[9][9];
for(int i = 0;i<9;i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j<9;j++){
        p[i][j] = 1;
    }
}

String str="";
for(int i = 0; i< 9; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j< 9; j++)
    {
        str+=p[i][j].toString +" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.deepToString(p);`

Comment: `Arrays.deepToString(p)`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch jinx. Almost exactly at the same moment.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know the rules. [Here](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/diehard/images/c/c2/Coca-Cola.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150518022453) you go.

Comment: I'll upvote the courageous person who puts `Arrays.deepToString(p);` as an answer.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've never heard that rule.

Comment: This code doesn't compile because `toString` doesn't have parenthesis..

Comment: @AndyTurner There aren't many [rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx_(children%27s_game)).

Comment: thank i will try it

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I had only come across the punch one. I didn't realize there was a get-out rule.

Comment: @AndyTurner I live in Atlanta. Don't know if the international rules committee has made a *final* determination (as the wikipedia entry notes, *varying rules and penalties that occur*).

Comment: Boston-area lurker here, confirming that "jinx-you-owe-me-a-coke" was definitely a thing when I was a kid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because:

1. You're trying to invoke a method on a primitive;
2. You're missing parentheses on that method call.

This:

```
str+=p[i][j].toString +" ";
```

should be

```
str+=Integer.toString(p[i][j]) +" ";
```

Or, easier:

```
    str+=p[i][j] +" ";
```

If you're going to build strings in loops, you should avoid concatenation, and use a `StringBuilder` instead:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i< 9; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j< 9; j++)
    {
        sb.append(p[i][j]);
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    // You maybe want sb.append("\n") here, if you want it on separate lines.
}    
String str = sb.toString();
```

Of course, the easier way in general to convert a 2D array to a string is using:

```
String str = Arrays.deepToString(p);
```

But this might not be in the format you desire.

Comment: It being Friday might have something to do with it.

Comment: Probably not; I don't think an appropriate overload is available.

Comment: @doormen No. And it would have been faster to try it yourself.

Comment: @AndyTurner: since your edit, my answer just looks ridiculous. It's gonna cost me.

Comment: @Bathsheba but you're very rich.

Comment: And don't forget to accept the answer that you find most useful. Sadly bribery is frowned upon.